# Convert Bio.Entrez class to string

Tags: python, string, biopython

I am currently using BioPython to query PubMed records from PMID's. I then store the desired information in a variable called abstract with a data type of:

```
class 'Bio.Entrez.Parser.StructureElement'>
```

For example if I print it I receive this:

```
{u'AbstractText': ['Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with elevated sympathetic activity. Both are independent cardiovascular ris....']}
```

I wish to write the text between the square brackets to a string. How can I quickly and efficiently do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you get your data from PubMed but if you need to query PubMed and get the abstract you can use the following snippet.

```
from Bio import Medline
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'my@email.com'

#a list of pubmed IDs
idlist = ['10024335']

#query PubMed
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=idlist, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
records = Medline.parse(handle)

#print the abstract of all records
for r in records:
    print(r['AB'])
```

**Output**

> 'Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with
>
> ...
>
> structural damage in hypercholesterolemic hypertensive subjects.'

Answer (score 0):

You should recognise this as a Python dictionary:

`{u'AbstractText': ['Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with elevated sympathetic activity. Both are independent cardiovascular ris....']}`

Here `'AbstractTest'` is a dictionary key, and `['Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with elevated sympathetic activity. Both are independent cardiovascular ris....']` its associated value.

Notice `['Hypercholesterolemia and hypertension are frequently associated with elevated sympathetic activity. Both are independent cardiovascular ris....']` is a Python list containing one string (shown truncated with dots).

So something like `my_dict['AbstractTest'][0]` would give you the first entry from this list.

Answer (score 0):

Since some elements of the list are of type `Bio.Entrez.Parser.StringElement`, you may want to to convert to a string (without the attributes and keys) with the str() builtin like this: `str(my_dict['AbstractTest'][0])`